# Nodejs Mongoose function won't execute promise

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a node.js script in which I'm trying to do something as simple as execute a Mongoose query and then read the response in the promise `.then`

The problem is no matter what I try, the `.then` never seems to happen. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my node file code:

```
const WorkOrder = require('../models/WorkOrder');

let promise = WorkOrder.findOne({}).exec();

promise.then(result => {
  console.log('result', result);
);
```

When I do a `console.log(WorkOrder.findOne({}).exec())` I get:

```
Promise {
  emitter:
   EventEmitter {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined },
  emitted: {},
  ended: false }
```

This a similar function is used in another part of the app (which uses redux) that has way more going on, this is just a super boiled down version just to see if I can query my database and then look at the result.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

exec does not return a promise, queries do.

```
const WorkOrder = require('../models/WorkOrder');

let promise = WorkOrder.findOne({});

promise.then(result => {
  console.log('result', result);
});
```

promise.exec() executes your query and receives a callback function as parameter:

```
const WorkOrder = require('../models/WorkOrder');

let promise = WorkOrder.findOne({});

promise.exec((err, result) => {
    if(err) console.log("err", err);
    else console.log("result", result);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, see this makes sense to me, however when I run the script, I still am not getting any console statements showing up :/ I just get `[nodemon] starting `node check_work_orders.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart`

Comment: That can happen if you never  call mongoose.connect()